# How to build mysql driver for qt?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I read a lot of instructions and tutorials how to do that, and I tried many of that, but 6 hours have gone and it's all the same. Please help...

*I know, there are some similar questions on stackoverflow but answers on them doesn't help.*

**Problem:**

I want to build Mysql driver for my qt program. According to instructions I did:

1) `set mysql=C:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.6` (full path is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6)

2)

```
cd C:\Qt_Sources\5.2.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql
qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=%mysql%\include" "LIBS+=%mysql%\lib\libmysql.lib"  mysql.pro
mingw32-make
```

**mingw32-make** from (C:\MinGW\bin)
After this I got:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt_Sources/5.2.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/
sqldrivers/mysql'
Makefile.Release:65: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt_Sources/5.2.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/s
qldrivers/mysql'
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

Also I tried **nmake** from (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin) and result is:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -
f Makefile.Release all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICO
DE -DWIN32 -DQT_EDITION=QT_EDITION_DESKTOP -DQT_EVAL -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_
NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQ
T_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"%mysql%\include" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtSql\5.
2.1" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtSql\5.2.1\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012\
include" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\
QtCore\5.2.1" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012\include\QtCore\5.2.1\QtCore" -I"C:\Qt\5.2.
1\msvc2012\include\QtCore" -I".moc\release" -I"..\..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-msvc201
2" -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\GOODSP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nmD5C6.tmp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Please explain what I did wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I finally resolve this issue...

I used **qmake** for another qt version, for me I think I used **qmake** from msvc2012, and tried to make it by mingw32-make and nmake (but nmake from visual studio 2011.. maybe this is the problem).

And solution is: 
Use **qmake** from **mingw48_32** directory (for me it's: `C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32`. Install qt sources with mingw, if you don't have it). After that all works fine with mingw32-make.